# Django REST framework parse request.data raising error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django view, I am trying this-

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def EmployeeList(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        employees = PersonalInfo.objects.all()
        serializer = PersonalInfoSerializer(employees, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        print data
        serializer = PersonalInfoSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

On posting data from postman, It raising attribute error

```
    {
    "detail": "JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"
}
```

when using `data = JSONParser().parse(request.data)` instead of `data = JSONParser().parse(request)` getting this error :

```
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use drf the request is instance of `rest_framework.request.Request` [requests](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/), but for `rest_framework.parsers` `JSONParser.parser` you need to send as parameter: `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest`, which you can get by `request._request`, but i think only you need is:

```
 serializer = PersonalInfoSerializer(data=request.data)
```